# Batch file to parse XML file and copy files to different folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch file (**test.bat**) that currently looks like this:

```
SET DIR_WORKING=%cd%
SET DIR_RELEASE=%DIR_WORKING%\Release

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%p in ('c:\WINDOWS\System32\find.exe "?define TRIALFILE" %DIR_WORKING%\Include.wxi') do (
   set PFILE=%%p

   for /F "tokens=*" %%s in ("%PFILE%") do set PFILE=%%s

   set PFILE="%PFILE:~23,250%"
   set PATCHFILE="%PFILE:~0,-3%"]
   
   COPY "%PATCHFILE" %DIR_RELEASE%
)
```

What I've been trying to accomplish is to parse an XML file called **Include.wxi**, get some .txt file paths, and then copy those .txt files over to the **Release** folder.

This is what **Include.wxi** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
   <?define TRIALFILE001="%DIR_WORKING%\Users\K\Documents\Test\v1.txt"?>
   <?define TRIALFILE002="%DIR_WORKING%\Users\K\Documents\Test\v2.txt"?>
</Include>
```

This is what my file structure looks like:

[image: File structure]

I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible. I've literally tried everything to solve this but CMD always gives me the most vague errors.. I can't seem to figure out how to get the nested for loops to work. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q50264822.txt"
SET "DIR_WORKING=u:\destdir"
SET "DIR_RELEASE=%DIR_WORKING%\Release"
MD "%dir_release%" 2>nul

FOR /f "tokens=3delims=<?=>" %%a IN ('c:\WINDOWS\System32\find.exe "?define TRIALFILE" "%filename1%" ' ) DO (
 CALL ECHO(COPY "%%~a" "%DIR_RELEASE%"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q50264822.txt` containing your data from `include.wxi` for my testing.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Fundamental to your problem is that you are not invoking the facilities of `delayed expansion` (#1 FAQ on SO/batch - use the `search` facility to locate many, many examples) as you are altering the value of a variable within a `code block` (parenthesised series of commands)

A further complication is your use of rabbit's ears. It is standard practice on SO to use the syntax `set "var=value"` for string assignments as this ensures stray trailing spaces on the line are ignored. It is also standard practice on SO to NOT assign quotes to a *value* as this generates problems with appropriately removing unwanted quotes when variables are concatenated.

So - having established the variables, create the destination directory (otherwise the `copy` commands will create a file) and use `2>nul` to suppress error messages in the destination already exists.

Then read the appropriate lines from your file using appropriate delimiters o select the filename required as token `3` to `%%a` - mentally noting that it will be quoted.

the `call copy` will first remove the quotes from `%%a` using `~`, then quote and *evaluate* the result, substituting for `%dir_working%`. The evaluation is performed in a subshell, so `delayed expansion` is not required.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo on
setlocal

SET "DIR_WORKING=%cd%"
SET "DIR_RELEASE=%DIR_WORKING%\Release"

if not exist "%DIR_RELEASE%" md "%DIR_RELEASE%"

for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=<?>" %%p in ('
 ""%systemroot%\system32\find.exe" "?define TRIALFILE" "%DIR_WORKING%\Include.wxi""
') do call :copyfrom %%p %%q
exit /b

:copyfrom
if not "%~1" == "define" exit /b 1
copy /y "%~3" "%DIR_RELEASE%"
exit /b 0
```

Delimiting by the special xml tag characters which are not
valid in file paths. The tokens `1-2` wil get the indenting
and the `define ...=...` or just the `define ...=...` if no
indenting found.

Calling the label `:copyfrom` with the tokens will treat the
arguments using cmdline rules. The indenting in a token will
be ignored as space. `define` will be expected as argument 1
and tested in the label to validate. The xml tag name before
the `=` character will be argument 2. The path to copy will
be after the `=` character which will be argument 3.

The command in the `for` loop has more than 2 double quotes
and double quotes on either end, so `cmd` will strip the outer
double quotes, thus I added extra double quotes on the outer,
so they get stripped instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would suffice:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('Find "?define TRIALFILE" include.wxi') Do @Copy "%%A" Release 2>Nul
```